# How to detect the scroll position of a `article` and add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four different article with different contents to it. All I have to do is when the scroll position reaches top position of a article that needs to get added with the class active. I tried with no success. Here is the code what I tried so far.

**HTML**

```
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

**CSS**

```
article{
    height: 800px;
    background-color: gray;
}
article:nth-child(2){
    background-color: blue;
}
article:nth-child(3){
    background-color: pink;
}
article:last-child{
    background-color: orange;
}
article.active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var scrollPosition = $('article').scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == scrollPosition) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0hkpqatq/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the absolute position of an element.

Here is an exemple :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('article').each(function () {
        var ArtOffsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var ArtOffsetBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        if (($(window).scrollTop() >= ArtOffsetTop) && ($(window).scrollTop() <= ArtOffsetBottom)) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

> [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s1jds2nf/)

---

I add a new variable `ArtOffsetBottom` to detect if `$(window).scrollTop()` is between top and bottom of an article.